# SVG embedded image is distorted

Tags: svg

I'm trying to make the responsive SVG but the following SVG is distorted on IE only.

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 196 421">
    <image
      width="123.904"
      height={401}
      xlinkHref={require("../../../styles/img/assets/day-serum-no-name.png")}
    />
</svg>
```

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What type of template is that? Please tag your question with react or angular or whatever it is.

Comment: it's pure svg template. @MichaelMullany

Comment: `height={401}` is not a valid XML attribute format. And there is no such SVG attribute `xlinkHref`.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] so we can see the problem in a real example.